# Regular expression that matches all specified characters in any order at the start of the line

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm looking for a regexp that matches any line that contains 'B', 'R', 'A' and 'S' (in any order) at the start. It would match all the following lines, except the last two.

```
BRASIL
BSRAIL
BARSILERO
BRASILERA
BRASILEÑA
BRASILEÑO
BARBADOS
BOSNIA AND HERZEGOVINA
```

I tried the following:

```
^(B|R|A|S){4}.*$
^(?=.*B)(?=.*R)(?=.*A)(?=.*S).*$
^(?=.{4})(?=.*B)(?=.*R)(?=.*A)(?=.*S).*$
^(?=.*B)(?=.*R)(?=.*A)(?=.*S){4}.*$
^(?=.*B){1}(?=.*R){1}(?=.*A){1}(?=.*S){1}.*$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```js
^([BRAS])(?!\1)([BRAS])(?!\1|\2)([BRAS])(?!\1|\2|\3)([BRAS])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/niVWhK/1/). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `([BRAS])` - Group 1: `B`, `R`, `A` or `S`
- `(?!\1)([BRAS])` - Group 2: `B`, `R`, `A` or `S` but not as in Group 1
- `(?!\1|\2)([BRAS])` - Group 3: `B`, `R`, `A` or `S` but not as in Group 1 and 2
- `(?!\1|\2|\3)([BRAS])` - Group 4: `B`, `R`, `A` or `S` but not as in Group 1, 2 and 3.

Note that when using the pattern with MySQL v.8, you need to double the backslashes:

```sql
"^([BRAS])(?!\\1)([BRAS])(?!\\1|\\2)([BRAS])(?!\\1|\\2|\\3)([BRAS])"
```

Comment: Maybe mention that lookaheads are a PCRE feature; the OP is not revealing which regex dialect they need, in violation of the [`regex` tag guidance](/tags/regex/info) (though their attempt suggests that they _tried_ to use PCRE features).

Comment: @tripleee Lookaheads are supported by a lot of engines: ECMAScript, Onigmo, .NET, Java, ICU, Python `re` / `regex`, Boost, not just PCRE. Right, considering the fact OP used lookarounds in their attempts, I assumed lookaheads are supported.

Comment: Interesting answer. I'm using this on MySQL, so it returns "BARBADOS" as well.

Comment: @M-Coder Is that MySQL v8? You need to double backslashes in MySQL regex declarations. I added this string to the answer. Note `BARBADOS` is matched because `\1`, `\2`, etc. are not treated as two-char combinations, but as octal char codes, and thus are not parsed as backreferences, but as string escape sequences.

Answer (score 3):

There are only 24 permutations :)

```
^(ABRS|BARS|RABS|ARBS|BRAS|RBAS|RBSA|BRSA|SRBA|RSBA|BSRA|SBRA|SARB|ASRB|RSAB|SRAB|ARSB|RASB|BASR|ABSR|SBAR|BSAR|ASBR|SABR)
```

You can shorten it a bit by grouping pairs of two:

```
^((AB|BA)(RS|SR)|(AR|RA)(BS|SB)|(AS|SA)(BR|RB)|(BR|RB)(AS|SA)|(BS|SB)(AR|RA)|(RS|SR)(AB|BA))
```

Each double pair matches 4 inputs, e.g., `(AB|BA)(RS|SR)` can match:

```
ABRS
ABSR
BARS
BASR
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using some *lookaheads* and limits:

```
^(?=.{0,3}B)(?=.{0,3}R)(?=.{0,3}A).{0,3}S
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FiXvts/2) (for full match output [see another demo](https://regex101.com/r/uWSfld/1))